# Can't Access Ajenti Web Panel Port in VirtualBox Debian 8

Tags: linux, nginx, server, debian

I'm trying to install [Anjenti](http://docs.ajenti.org/en/latest/man/install.html) Server Admin Panel on Debian 8 and [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/). I have removed Apache.

The website connects at 127.0.0.1:8888, but I cannot access Ajenti.

---

I used the Ajenti Automatic Installation. It completed with:

[image: completed install]

But it does not connect in the browser:

```
Unable to connect  
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.
```

---

#### VirtualBox Server

Portforwading

[image: port forwarding]

Address in use

[image: address in use]

`sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 8000`

[image: netstat]

---

#### Config

[Digital Ocean answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ajenti-port-not-working-on-debian) says to disable SSL in the config. It is already disabled.

**config.yml**

```
auth:
  allow_sudo: true
  emails: {}
  provider: os
bind:
  host: 0.0.0.0
  mode: tcp
  port: 8000
color: default
max_sessions: 9
name: debian
ssl:
  certificate:
  client_auth:
    certificates: []
    enable: false
    force: false
  enable: false
```

I changed the Host to 127.0.0.1 and Port to 7000. It says `Binding to [127.0.0.1]:7000`.

[image: port 7000]

I get the same connection error:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:7000.
```

I tried adding it to Portfowarding. I tries to connect but the loading icon just keeps spinning.

[image: portfowarding 7000]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the port in IP tables.

```
root@debian:/# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 --jump ACCEPT
root@debian:/# iptables-save
```

Comment: I added Host Port 8888 and 7000 to iptables. 8888 is the main site. When I visit Ajenti at 7000 it now directs to the main site. What should be the Guest Port for Ajenti?